# How can I remove a user as an admin by using ASP.NET Core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have tried a lot of ways and functions to do this function, but it didn't work - can someone help me please, to solve this problem?

I get an error I don't understand:

> DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(string id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var applicationuser = await db.ApplicationUsers.FindAsync(id);

    if (applicationuser == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(applicationuser);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(ApplicationUser user)
{
    db.ApplicationUsers.Remove(user);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: Please add your request to the Delete method.

Comment: public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Governorate { get; set; }

        public string  City { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 1):

as far as I kown,the [Timestamp] Attribute may cause this error

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BjEX.gif)

and if it is the reason caused the error ,you could try this code in your context class

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.TimeStamp).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Comment: public class ApplicationUser:IdentityUser
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Governorate { get; set; }

        public string  City { get; set; }
    } This is  the application user model

Comment: I've tested with your class,and there seems no error.Have you missed any attributes in your model class(both ApplicationUser and IdentityUser)?And could you show me more details of the dbcontext,the version of your ef core and asp.net core ?You could also open the log to the highest level to check  if any other error info.

Comment: Can i have your email to send you the code

Comment: Sorry,I can't tell you my e-mail accroding to the policy,could you upload your codes to Github instead?